# Rotate IPv6 for curl commands?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ip, curl

I have a bash script that needs to run curl several thousand times against different URLs.

Each time curl is run, I want to use a random IPv6 address from the /64 that's assigned to my VPS.

I read somewhere that this was possible to do (and it looked quite easy), I just can't find the article on it anymore.

It doesn't matter what IPv6 address is used, any random one from my machine will work.

I can do it on an Ubuntu or Debian vps, in case that makes a difference.